# How to build rectangles on top of each other in html

Tags: html

I have built this html

aiming to get this structure

[image]

my html

```html
<div style="border: solid;">
  Rec 1

</div>
<div style="border: solid;width:20%;display: inline-block;margin:0;padding:0;">
  Rec 2
</div>
<div style="border: solid;width:60%;display: inline-block;margin:0;padding:0;">
  Rec 3
</div>
<div style="border: solid;width:20%;display: inline-block;margin:0;padding:0;">
  Rec 4
</div>
```

but my code gives me this

[image]

How to fix it and get desired design

Comment: number 4 doesnt fit, give it more space and it will behave like expected, even though you set width 20, 60, 20 wich is 100%. its actually more than that because of the borders

Comment: It's because you're using `display: inline-block`. A non-zero font-size of the items' parent means any whitespace will contribute. Try with `float` instead, or a table, since this is basically a tabular layout.

Comment: @Utkanos floar made them all on top of each other, what i want same as the first image

Comment: There is no reason at all why float would result in what you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrapp rec2,3 and 4 in a flex container
Here is the solution

```css
   #flex-container{
        display: flex;
    }
```

```html
<div style="border: solid;">
        Rec 1

    </div>
    <div id="flex-container">
        <div style="border: solid;width:20%;display: inline-block;margin:0;padding:0;">
            Rec 2
        </div>
        <div style="border: solid;width:60%;display: inline-block;margin:0;padding:0;">
            Rec 3
        </div>
        <div style="border: solid;width:20%;display: inline-block;margin:0;padding:0;">
            Rec 4
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `box-sizing: border-box` for Rec 2,3,4 `<div>` style.
2. Use comment tag(link two lines of `<div>`) to remove the space created by the line break between the `<div>`

```html
<div style="border: solid;">
  Rec 1
</div>
<div style="border: solid;width:20%;display: inline-block;margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;">
  Rec 2
</div><!--
--><div style="border: solid;width:60%;display: inline-block;margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;">
  Rec 3
</div><!--
--><div style="border: solid;width:20%;display: inline-block;margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;">
  Rec 4
</div>
```